# Boolean and Integer are strings after serialization

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, boolean, metadata

I'm using WordPress [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to save an array like

```
$obj = array(
    'array' => array(1, 'zwei', !!3),
    'string' => 'abc',
    'bool' => true,
    'bool2' => false,
    'integer' => 1,
    'integer2' => 17
);

update_post_meta($post_ID, 'my-key', $obj);
```

however if I check the raw field i get

```
a:6:{s:5:"array";a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:4:"zwei";i:2;s:1:"1";}s:6:"string";s:3:"abc";s:4:"bool";s:1:"1";s:5:"bool2";s:1:"0";s:7:"integer";i:1;s:8:"integer2";i:17;}
```

while it should be

```
a:6:{s:5:"array";a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:4:"zwei";i:2;b:1;}s:6:"string";s:3:"abc";s:4:"bool";b:1;s:5:"bool2";b:0;s:7:"integer";i:1;s:8:"integer2";i:17;}
```

You may notice that all boolean are stored as string (`b:1 = s:1:"1"`)

The problem is only on certain WordPress installations and not on every one. I've also checked the [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function which is working correct (returns `b:1`)

Also using [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
get_post_meta($post_ID, 'my-key', true);
```

and checkin the value with [is_bool](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php) returns false (obviously)

**EDIT:** just noticed also integers get saved as strings

Comment: Are there any 'sanitize_meta' filters, maybe from certain plugins, being applied on the installations where this is happening? Search the codebase for `add_filter('sanitize_`

Comment: what version of wordpress are you using? Can you update wp and then check again? I've installed an wp 3.5.2 and the issue was there, after I've updated to 3.6.1 the issue was fixed

Comment: WordPress >= 3.6 uses [wp_unslash](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L119) while 3.5.2 still uses [stripslashes_deep](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L119)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update_post_meta uses update_metadata you can find it's code [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L101)  in that function if you have a look [at line 119](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L119) you will see that the meta_value is passed to [wp_unslash](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unslash) which return value is a string (the function that changes the data type is [stripslashes_deep](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep))

As a workaround you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the value before passing it to [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

EDIT:
Found the issue: before 3.6.0 update_metadata had on line 117 this code:

```
$meta_key = stripslashes($meta_key)
```

[stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) is a php function that returns a string.
as of 3.6.0 that line looks like:

```
$meta_key = wp_unslash($meta_key);
```

which stripslashes only string type meta_keys.

An update to wordpress 3.6.0 or above will fix the issue.

Comment: best answer so far! but wp_unslash uses [stripslashes_deep](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1429) which converts only strings

Comment: Ok I've checked the source and it seems THIS is the problem! You save me tons of headache!

Comment: Yes, Wordpress 3.6.0 should not unslash any longer. If it still does, please report this.